# Generate token given username and password in identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

IdentityServer4 has example to generate token for a given client. How do we generate token for a given username and password for a given client using IdentityServer4 with EntityFrameworkCore for authenticating a web api end point?